# how to have "crontab -e" emit an "installing new crontab" email

Tags: cron

When I update a crontab, a message is emitted on the screen:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

Is it possible to configure it (cron or crontab or some other system config) so that it also sends out an email to a designated address?

My environment is as follows:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dev 3.12.62-60.64.8-default #1 SMP Tue Oct 18 12:21:38 UTC 2016 (42e0a66) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I do use `aide` but I was looking for an instantaneous alert.

Answer (score 2):

```
if crontab -e; then crontab -l | mail -s "New cron table installed for $(whoami) on $(hostname -s)" youremail@example.com; fi
```